# Using c++ regex and too slow result

Tags: c++, regex

speed is very very important criterion to me. this is my string

```
DataInfoBlock1 {

    Some description
}

DataInfoBlock2 {

    Some other informations
}

Block3 {

    Anything = vl;
    Anything = vl;
    Anything = vl;
    Anything = vl;
    Anything = vl;
    Anything = vl;
    Anything = vl;
    Anything = vl;
    Anything = vl;
    Anything = vl;
    Anything = vl;
    Anything = vl;
    Anything = vl;
    Anything = vl;
    Anything = vl;
    Anything = vl;
    Anything = vl;
    Anything = vl;
    Anything = vl;
    Anything = vl;
    Anything = vl;
    Anything = vl;
    Anything = vl;
    Anything = vl;
    Anything = vl;
    Anything = vl;
    Anything = vl;
    Anything = vl;
    Anything = vl;
    Anything = vl;
    Anything = vl;
    Anything = vl;
    Anything = vl;
    Anything = vl;
    Anything = vl;
    Anything = vl;
    Anything = vl;
    Anything = vl;
    Anything = vl;
    Anything = vl;
    Anything = vl;
    Anything = vl;
    Anything = vl;
    Anything = vl;
    Anything = vl;
    Anything = vl;
    Anything = vl;
    Anything = vl;
    Anything = vl;
    Anything = vl;
    Anything = vl;
    Anything = vl;
    Anything = vl;
    Anything = vl;
    Anything = vl;
    Anything = vl;
    Anything = vl;
    Anything = vl;
    Anything = vl;
    Anything = vl;
    Anything = vl;
    Anything = vl;
    Anything = vl;
    Anything = vl;
    Anything = vl;
    Anything = vl;
}
```

i want to get each block name and inside content and i am using c++ regex and this is my regex and regex search code

```
smatch Matches;
string Rgx("[[:blank:]]*([^]*?)[[:blank:]]*[{][[:blank:]]*([^]*?)[[:blank:]]*[}]", regex::optimize);

while(regex_search(str, Matches, Rgx))
{

}
```

and my result is

```
Array[1]
    Array[0] => DataInfoBlock1 {

        Some description
    }
    Array[1] => DataInfoBlock1
    Array[2] => Some description
,
...
...
```

i got full matche, block name and inside data but speed is very very bad (it took about a second) to get matches!!! what should i do to get result very very faster? is this regex optimize ? what regex i have to use to get result like this but in the very very faster time?

Comment: Does `[^]` work? You'd probably improve performance by making that more explicit.  Also using `+` instead of `*`. I think. I don't know regexes well.

Comment: Everything worked successfully but my problem is speed (done time)

Comment: You tagged the question as boost - are you using boost regex or the C++11+ regex library? You tagged it as pcre but that's not pcre syntax http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/perl_syntax.html.

Comment: as i said in my question, i am using normal c++ regex. i used boost and pcre tags to if there is the better offer in pcre or boost, guide me with them.

Comment: @user216086: That's not what tags are for, don't do that

Comment: I'm trying to do tests, but I can't get accurate results.  If you're willing to look at inaccurate results, tightening the `[^]` seems to make a huge speed difference (10x?), and changing the `*` to `+` gets me another 10x improvement.  It's all invalid since I don't know your data and the regexes are clearly failing though. :( http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d9aa66c5ecbf641d

Comment: i found out using `[[:blank:]]*` Reduce speed very much !!!! changing `*` to `+` just get when match with 1 and more but i need to match with zero and more (i need to use `*` at all))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try this:

```
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>

const std::string s = R"~(
DataInfoBlock1 {

    Some description
}

DataInfoBlock2 {

    Some other informations
}

Block3 {

    Anything = vl;
    Anything = vl;
}
)~";

int main()
{    
    std::regex e(R"~((\w+)\s+\{([^}]+)\})~", std::regex::optimize);

    std::sregex_iterator iter(s.begin(), s.end(), e);
    std::sregex_iterator end;

    for(; iter != end; ++iter)
    {
        std::cout << "-----------------------------" << '\n';
        std::cout << "name: " << iter->str(1) << '\n';
        std::cout << "contents: " << iter->str(2) << '\n';
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
-----------------------------
name: DataInfoBlock1
contents: 

    Some description

-----------------------------
name: DataInfoBlock2
contents: 

    Some other informations

-----------------------------
name: Block3
contents: 

    Anything = vl;
    Anything = vl;
```

**[Tested Here](https://regex101.com/r/zU3mO1/1)**

Comment: Amazing !!! That was great ... but still wait for better and faster regex ... what are those (~) and (R) ?

Comment: @user216086 The `R"~()~"` are all part of what is called a [raw string literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal). You can choose what you like to surround the parentheses (if anything) `R"()"`. The important thing is to select something not likely to be contained in the string itself. Normal string literals require special characters to be escaped (including the escape character itself: `"\\"` - for a single backslash). Raw strings don't contain any escape characters so a single backslash is no longer an escape code.

Comment: @user216086 This is useful for `regex` where escaping can get confusing (regex has its own escapes on top of `C++`. Also *raw strings* can be mulitiline (no `"\n"` end of line escape codes). A new line is literally a new line.

Comment: Can you say to me what should i do to skip any description `/* anything here */ or // in one line` in my content? i means do not get any block and content when they are in `/* anything here */ or // in one line` .. what regex i have to use to skip descriptions ?